# PWD doesn't work in a Makefile for a Linux kernel module

Tags: linux, makefile, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I'm trying to write a simple hello world kernel module. I'm working in Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS on Virtual Box. In the directory /usr/src I created a directory named hello and inside that hello directory I've created hello.c and a makefile. Here is my makefile:

```
obj-m += hello.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

When I make the command "sudo make" I get this output:

```
make -C /lib/modules/5.3.0-28-generic/build M= modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.3.0-28-generic'
make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'arch/x89/tools/relocs_32.c', needed by 'arch/x86/tools/relocs_32.o'. Stop.
arch/x86/Makefile:232: recipe for target 'archscripts' failed
make[1]: *** [archscripts] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.3.0-28-generic'
makefile:4: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I've tried a few variations of my makefile including changing "PWD" to "shell pwd". I've installed all the essential tools and libraries as far as I know. What could be the problem here?

Comment: What does `x89` mean in your log?

Answer (score 3):

Variable `PWD` is set by the **shell**, so your Makefile relies on `make` invocation to be performed from the shell, as we normally do when type `make` in the terminal.

But `sudo make` executes `make` from a plain user environment. This environment **lacks** for `PWD` variable, so your Makefile behaves incorrectly. This can be found from your output:

```
make -C /lib/modules/5.3.0-28-generic/build M= modules
```

Use `$(shell pwd)` expression instead, it is more reliable:

```
obj-m += hello.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(shell pwd) modules
clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(shell pwd) clean
```

Alternatively, you may call `make` with root privileges using this way:

```
sudo /bin/sh -c make
```

This way `make` is executed not from the plain root environment, but under an intermediate shell. This shell sets `PWD` variable.

**Update**

As noted by @Ian Abbott in the comments, another alternative for `$(PWD)` is `$(CURDIR)`. Variable `CURDIR` is set by the `make` itself (precisely, by **GNU** Make). See also that question: [bash: What is the difference between PWD and CURDIR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52437728/bash-what-is-the-difference-between-pwd-and-curdir).

Comment: Another option is to use `$(CURDIR)`. The `CURDIR` variable is set by GNU Make.

Comment: @IanAbbott: Thanks for note, I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your **Makefile** should look like this

```
obj-m += hello.o
```

Then your build command will look like

```sh
make -C $KDIR M=$PWD
```

Where **$KDIR** is the source tree of your kernel build.

is the way. The rest is handled by the kbuild system.

Please refer to refer to the official documentation for [building off-tree modules](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt)