# How to retrieve the current shell directory from Makefile on Windows

Tags: windows, makefile, gnu-make, mingw-w64

I believe I understand reasonably well the Makefile variables such as `$(CURDIR)`, etc... (well you never know, sometimes you believe you understand something, but you don't really)

What I'm really after is `$(PWD)`, i.e. the current **shell** directory rather than the current **make** directory.
To illustrate the various concepts, I've put together a simple example:

`/root/dir1/dir2/dir3/Makefile.linux`

```
all:
    @echo
    @echo "current dir = $(CURDIR)"
    @echo "last_make   = $(realpath $(dir $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))))"
    @echo "pwd         = $(PWD)"
```

If you execute the following commands here is what you get:

Option 1: `cd /root ; make --directory ./dir1/dir2/dir3 --makefile Makefile.linux`

```
make: Entering directory '/root/dir1/dir2/dir3'
current dir = /root/dir1/dir2/dir3
last_make   = /root/dir1/dir2/dir3
pwd         = /root
make: Leaving directory '/root/dir1/dir2/dir3'
```

Option 2: `cd /root ; make --makefile  ./dir1/dir2/dir3/Makefile.linux`

```
current dir = /root
last_make   = /root/dir1/dir2/dir3
pwd         = /root
```

In the above, `$(PWD)` is doing what I expect.
Now, the problem is that I do not obtain the same behavior on Windows. The only thing that's needed is a Windows port of `make` such as the [ezwinport](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ezwinports/files/make-4.4.1-without-guile-w32-bin.zip/download) or possibly a `mingw32-make` that comes in many toolchains, for example [WinLibs](https://winlibs.com/). Here is the equivalent Makfile:

`C:/root/dir1/dir2/dir3/Makefile.win64`

```
all:
    @echo "current dir = $(CURDIR)"
    @echo "last_make   = $(realpath $(dir $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))))"
    @echo "pwd1        = $(PWD)"
    @echo "pwd2        = $(shell cd)"
    @echo "pwd3        = $(shell echo %CD%)"
    @echo "pwd4        = $(shell echo %PWD%)"
```

I was under the impression that `$(PWD)` was a built-in make variable, and therefore I was expecting it to work transparently on Windows.
I've just seen [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52437728/bash-what-is-the-difference-between-pwd-and-curdir) and realized that it's not the case. Therefore, it's not surprising that `pwd1` is not correct. I tried a few other variants, see my `pwd2`, `pwd3` and `pwd4` attempts. The Option 2 result appears correct, but not the Option 1 result:

Option 1: `cd C:/root ; make --directory ./dir1/dir2/dir3 --makefile Makefile.win64`

```
make: Entering directory 'C:/root/dir1/dir2/dir3'
"current dir = C:/root/dir1/dir2/dir3"
"last_make   = C:/root/dir1/dir2/dir3"
"pwd1        = "
"pwd2        = C:\root\dir1\dir2\dir3"
"pwd3        = C:\root\dir1\dir2\dir3"
"pwd4        = ECHO is off."
make: Leaving directory 'C:/root/dir1/dir2/dir3'
```

Option 2: `cd C:/root ; make --makefile  ./dir1/dir2/dir3/Makefile.win64`

```
"current dir = C:/root"
"last_make   = C:/root/Makefile_pwd/dir1/dir2/dir3"
"pwd1        = "
"pwd2        = C:\root"
"pwd3        = C:\root"
"pwd4        = ECHO is off."
```

Is this an intrinsic limitation of the Windows `cmd` shell ? or is there a clever way to obtain the same behavior as on Linux ?

PS: There is a related discussion over here, but does not really bring me a solution:
[makefile to support PWD in mac and windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71760845/makefile-to-support-pwd-in-mac-and-windows)

Comment: Note that `PWD` is lying in this case, since it is not in fact the directory of a shell that's actually guaranteed to exist. If it is set, it just happens to be a directory used by *some* shell somewhere up the chain. If you really need separate directories like this, use `make -f` rather than `make -C`.

Comment: Also, `make -C` is normally only used for recursive make, but Recursive Make Considered Harmful.

Comment: I don't see anything inherently wrong with `make -C` -- there are plausible reasons to use it beyond recursive `make` -- but I do question what you want it for, that also requires knowledge of the working directory when `make` was launched.

Comment: What I want this for is a question of its own - I deliberately didn't say anything about it because it would only have brought confusion. I appreciate that the effect I'm trying to achieve is not something that would be used in a robust and well-designed infrastructure (wich you seem to have spotted too !). Besides why ? (which is a very legitimate question), I'm purely interested in how ?

Comment: The only reliable and portable way to do what you want today is to pass the "original" directory to make on the command line.  On a POSIX system you can run `make PWD=$(pwd)`  I am not a Windows person so I'm not sure what the equivalent would be on Windows.  I guess `make PWD=%CD%` would work?